# Propel 1.6 has some trouble to generate schema from Sybase 15.7

Tags: php, sybase, propel

With a PHP ZF2 project I have to generate a schema of a database (Sybase 15.7) with Propel 1.6, but after that Propel get connected to the database it has some problem to generate the schema.

I have this error message:

> [ propel - schema - reverse ] Reading database structure...
>   [ propel - schema - reverse ] There was an error building XML message frim the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtproperties']

There is my Propel configuration:

```
propel.project = {{projectName}}
propel.database = mssql
propel.database.url = dblib:Driver=FreeTDS; host={{ipServer}}:{{portServer}};
propel.database.user = {{user}}
propel.database.password = {{password}}
propel.schema.dir = ${project.build}
propel.conf.dir = ${project.build}
propel.namespace.om = om
propel.namespace.map = map
propel.namespace.autoPackage = true
propel.packageObjectModel = true
```

Sounds that propel try to generate the schema with MySQL request rather than Sybase request but I don't handle where it could be configurate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your DB is not supported.
Propel supports the following databases:

- MySQL MS SQL Server
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Oracle